# AS3 ClickToGoToAndStop function from main timeline targeted to frame within movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm creating a website in flash and I'm having trouble finding what code to use for timeline and movieclip navigation.  Right now I have my main navigation buttons on the main timeline, and a separate animation that serves as my content container on a movieclip within the main timeline.  I don't know how to make it so that when I click a button on the main timeline to have it navigate to a frame within the content movieclip.  I've found many troubleshooters regarding how to control the main timeline from within a movieclip, which is the opposite of what I'm trying to do.

I also have MouseOut handlers on the buttons which direct to mouse out animations on the main timeline.

```
HomeBtn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, fl_MouseOutHandler_1);
Num2Btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, fl_MouseOutHandler_2);
ThrdBtn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, fl_MouseOutHandler_3);

function fl_MouseOutHandler_1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndPlay(2);
    trace("Moused out");
}

function fl_MouseOutHandler_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndPlay(30);
    trace("Moused out");
}

function fl_MouseOutHandler_3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndPlay(56);
    trace("Moused out");
}
```

I would like it if I could add a function like this:

```
function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(x);
}
```

But with a path targeted within the movieclip, I know it may sound like a simple question but I'm relatively new to flash.

Comment: not to be too critical, but if your building a website , i think your best option is to learn the basics... Try www.FFiles.com have great examples there plus you get the source code aswell...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To target the content movieclip:

**1. Give it an instance name.**
Select it on the stage and enter a name in the  textfield on the Properties panel. Call it something like 'contentClip'.

**2. Access it in your code using the instance name.**

```
contentClip.gotoAndStop(30);
```

Will make the content clip go to frame 30.

Comment: Cadin nailed it. you can also label the frame in said movie clip the same way (select the frame on the time line then in properties give it a name) I prefer this as I may name it something like "mouseOut" in case i alter the animation i need not worry about the exact frame number. you'd do that `contentClip.gotoAndStop("mouseOut");`